# How do I reference images in a specfic folder called "images" two subdirectories in

Tags: php, image, subdirectory

I have tried */./images/ and other variations with no success. 
Where does the directory of images start? Anything under the directory the script will read. With Trailing slash

`$files_path="/";`

```
//Enter the full server path to where the directory starts. 
$full_server="c:/xampp/htdocs/location/video/";
```

Comment: `.` is the current directory. `..` is the previous directory. A preceding `/` without a dot in front of it will go to the base url of the "public" portion of the web server. So, maybe try `./images/` ... or similar with that "dot" in front. Or simply omit the `./` and use `images/`.    ....... But this comment *//Enter the full server path to where the directory starts.*  gives me some pause. Can you provide a link where these instructions are from and context on what project you are working on?

Comment: I am looking for a subdirectory, the other direction, for example, if the root folder is "directory" the subdirectories directories within it, only skipping the first subdirectory folders and looking at the contents of the next subdirectory folder entitled "images"

Comment: Ok i see. Well possibly you should try and look at "sub directories" as how the operating system sees them. You cant just as you say *skipping the first subdirectory folders*, instead you need a specific directory to go into to do the "skipping".  .... Side Note: I now understand why you used an asterisk (wildcard) in your question. Possibly what you desire is a *recursive* operation, in regards to your words *I have tried */./images/ and other variations with no success*.

Comment: Update your question title to be "How to recursively traverse sub directories for a specific folder name" or similar. Your question title presently doesn't garner the attention it needs on how it is worded. .... Also, unless you welcome downvotes, you should show some coding attempts. Presently all you have is variable declarations.

Comment: Forget what I last said. It may or may not apply to your problem. .... Instead I would advise you to explain in more detail what it is you are trying to solve. And show your current source code. The variable declarations you have are pure guess work to decipher from an outside observer. It was guesswork by me. This is actually unacceptable. (Unless you like downvotes).

Comment: Your right I only seem to get downvotes..I see if I cant reword this better.